# Raspberry PI3 - Node version

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi3

My very first Raspberry and I want to install the Smart-mirror. When running npm start, it launch the home screen, but also coming with this error:

> Error: The module '/home/pi/smart-    mirror/node_modules/grpc/node/extension_binary/grpc_node.node' was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION 48. This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 51. Please try re-compiling or re-installing the module (for instance, using 'npm rebuild' or 'npm install')

I tried both, but ending up with the same error.

How do I fix it?

Comment: This belongs in http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Don't duplicate posts next time: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59942/raspberry-pi3-node-version